# WordPress, JS, HTML CSS верстка

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, вёрстка

Здравствуйте [на сайте](https://yahoomma.site/cases/).
После нажатия на кнопку "показать еще" изображения перестают отображаться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переведите ваш вопрос на русский.

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста консоль

Answer (score 1):

У Вас проблема в том, что после клика по кнопке пропадает обёртка **DIV class="container"**

[image: На скрине видим фрагмент до и после клика]

Важно то, как вы делаете кнопку далее... Плагином, то смотреть настройки и корректно указать обёртку для вставки следующих блоков. Если самостоятельно написали, смотрите куда вставляете новый контент.